# Не отправляются данные формы Bootstrap

Tags: html, django

У мене есть код html c формой которая должна отправлятся (форма взята с bootstrap) - но при просмотре в браузере видно что отправляется  только токен, не могу понять что пошло не так (((

````
    <title>  </title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <form method="post" class="post-form" action="{% url 'item-list' %}">{% 
            csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                      <div class="col-sm-7">
                          <span class="align-middle">
                            <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-4" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
                              <option selected>    </option>
                                {% for item in shop %}
                                     <option value="1">{{ item }}</option>
                                {% empty %}
                                    <option value="1">None</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                          </span>
                      </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
                          <option selected>  </option>
                                {% for item in department %}
                                    <option value="1">{{ item}}</option>
                                {% empty %}
                                    <option value="1">None</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                <br>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                    <span class="align-middle">
                         <div class="col-10">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sumbit</button>
                         </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
         </div>
       </form>

  </body>
</html>  ```
````

Comment: У вас ни у каких полей формы не прописан name, вот ничего и не отправляется

Answer (score 0):

Здесь надо было добавить:

```
name  <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-4" aria-label=".form-select-lg example" name="question">
```

И убрать:

```
option value <option value="1">{
```